# Highcharts iOS Swift : Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_HIAnimationOptionsObject

Tags: ios, highcharts

when i try to disable animation i get -
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_HIAnimationOptionsObject

below is my code :

```
let animation = HIAnimationOptionsObject()
    animation.duration = 0
    chart.animation = animation
    
    options.chart = chart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable animation in this way:

```
let animation = HIAnimationOptionsObject()
animation.duration = 0
plotOptions.series.animation = animation
```

Comment: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_HIAnimationOptionsObject

Comment: @Reena are you able to share the whole config to reproduce this issue?

Comment: let plotOptions = HIPlotOptions()
        plotOptions.series = HISeries()
        
        let dataLabels = HIDataLabels()        
        dataLabels.enabled = true
        dataLabels.crop = true
        dataLabels.align = "right"
        
        plotOptions.series.dataLabels = [dataLabels]
        
        let animation = HIAnimationOptionsObject()
        animation.duration = 0
        plotOptions.series.animation = animation

Comment: This part of the code is not enough. Could you reproduce your issue on some demo to see the problem?